# What does it mean when a salary range starts with C?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

```
C$65k - 75k
^
```

Is this a bug or it represents something?

[image]

Comment: Maybe canadian dollar? Well, Wiki agrees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_dollar

Comment: I'd guess it means Canadian dollars, but that's not a standard abbreviation: it could also refer to [Cayman Islands dollars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayman_Islands_dollar) or [Nicaraguan córdoba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_c%C3%B3rdoba)!

Comment: Oh, right - the european side of me is not used with stuff like that

Comment: Or possible *circa* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's Canadian Dollars.

There's now a tooltip with the currency description, as Adelin suggested in his answer.

Comment: Nice! Impressive turnaround time on that improvement.

Answer (score 15):

Tom suggests in the comments it is the Canadian Dollar.

Since displaying other currencies is a possibility, I'd implement an on-hover feature that describes in words the currency, to avoid confusion, something like:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, good idea - done!